# How do I mount an Exchange mail store from the Windows Command Line?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2003, scripting

Our Exchange server is running `Exchange Server 2003 Standard` on the `Windows Server 2003 platform`.  We're dealing with the mail store size issue, where if the mail store goes over the limit, it gets dismounted.

While we are working with the powers-that-be on a policy that will prevent this happening in the future, I would like to see if it is possible to re-mount the mail store via the Windows CLI.  I'm already monitoring the Event Logs and alerting on mail store warnings and dismounts - I'm just tired of getting up at 5am to manually re-mount the store while the political wars ensue.

My alerting tools have the ability to execute a batch script when an alert is generated.  I would greatly prefer a native CLI option.  I'm not too keen on running some random vbscript found on the Internet and I don't really care to spend my time debugging someone else's code.  PowerShell might be an option, if it can be triggered  from the CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sympathise but with exchange 2003 your options may be a little limited - it's not designed to be manipulated via the shell really. I'm not trying to be negative here, just realistic.

The only idea I have is to do a net stop and then a net start command on the information store service - this should remount the store. It's been a while since I've worked with Exchange 2003 but I think the 2 lines of batch script below will do it.

```
net stop "Microsoft Exchange Information Store"
net start "Microsoft Exchange Information Store"
```

(note the quotes around the service name)

Oh and I'm sure you've seen the setting [discussed here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/bump-the-size-of-your-information-store-to-75gb-exchange-2003-standard-edition-only/6063252), but under the circumstances I am sure you won't mind me making sure.

Comment: This has been working well for the last few months.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google gave me this
[Mount/Dismount/Delete a Mailbox store from CMD](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows2000/AdminTips/Exchange/MountDismountDeleteaMailboxStorefromtheCommandLine.html)

Comment: Looks like you posted this answer while I was editing my question.  I've seen quite a few vbscript options already, the few I've been willing to try didn't work, and I'm really trying to avoid that altogether.  Please see my updated question.

Comment: :) Too fast :).

Answer (score 0):

I think your option may be limited on the 2003 platform. Maybe there's powershell options open to you, but I suspect the official solution is to write a .NET application.